# facing an error : anaconda is not starting

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

### **Getting this error while starting any of the anaconda program.. Directly clicking is not helping.. and Anaconda navigator or jupyter notebook or spyder is not opening up. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

```
spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 36, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.external import lockfile
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\lockfile.py", line 30, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Documents\python\datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pytz
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pytz.tzinfo import unpickler, BaseTzInfo
  File "C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytz\tzinfo.py", line 3, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo
ImportError: cannot import name 'timedelta' from 'datetime' (C:\Users\Happyselling.in\Documents\python\datetime.py)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The script is importing the `datetime` module from your local folder `Documents\python\datetime.py`, instead of the one from Anaconda installation.